# Simple paths with halt in between in directed graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have two problems related to paths in a directed graph. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph with source $s \in V$ and target $t \in V$. Let $v \in V \setminus \{s,t\}$ be another vertex in $G$.

1. Find a simple directed path¹ from $s$ to $t$ through $v$.
2. Find a simple directed path from $s$ to $t$ that goes through two fixed edges in $G$.

I do not know if there are polynomial time algorithms for them. Does anyone have solutions or references for them?

---

1. A simple directed path does not allow any vertex to appear more than once.

Comment: For problem 1, see [this post](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9626/viapath-as-a-maximum-flow-problem) on cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

As Tsuyoshi Ito notes, the first problem can be solved using network flow. This was described in detail in [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9626/viapath-as-a-maximum-flow-problem).